# is there a way to save Gurobi objects in python?

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, gurobi

I have many variables with multiple indexes such as:
    `flow[i,j,k]`
with Gurobi variable names: `flow_1_1_1, ..., flow_1_2_3`, etc.

If the Gurobi model objects are global variables then the solution values can be accessed as `flow[i,j,k].x`

My question is is there a way to store "flow" object and load it later for reoptimizing? Unfortunately pickle is not supported.

if not, what are my best options?

Comment: code format for readability

Answer (score 0):

If the model does not change at all, you might export and later import the [MST-File](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/6.0/refman/mst_format.html)

I am afraid, you are often better off by creating your own data structure and save the `x`-values there with your indices. In case of later reoptimization you simply recreate your model and set `.start` to your saved values.

Note, that you will always lose your presolve-, root-relaxiation-, root-node- and branch-and-bound-informations with this approach. I have no experience, if some of the [model-file-formats](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/6.0/refman/model_file_formats.html) might help for a better reoptimization-start.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to recovery values of yours variables after optimizing. And then use those for reoptimization like below (sol_U is dictionnary in wich we recovery the data of the varialbe vU).

```css
m.optimize()
    status = m.status
    if status == GRB.Status.OPTIMAL:
        sol_V=m.getAttr('x', vV)
        sol_U=m.getAttr('x', vU)
        print('Optimization status was %d' % status)
        print('The optimal objective is %g' % m.objVal)

        for e in OpEq:
            for bl in Blocs:
                for t in Te:
                    if sol_U[bl,t, e] > 0.1:
                        print('u_(%s,%i,%s)-> %f' % (bl,t,e, sol_U[bl,t, e]))
                          
        sol_V = m.getAttr('x', vV)
        for op in Op_:    
            for bl in BlocsR:
                for t in Te:
                    if sol_V[bl,t,op] > 0.1:
                        print('v_(%s,%i,%i)-> %f' % (bl,t,op, sol_V[bl,t, op]))
```